# VOLTTRON driver development module not found

Tags: python, volttron

On VOLTTRON 7.0.x I created a simple driver to interact with a rest XML API to get some data, but when I reinstall the master driver agent to make use of my new driver I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`

Full trace back:

```
2021-12-09 17:37:09,505 (master_driveragent-4.0 2192707) <stderr> ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-12-09 17:37:09,505 (master_driveragent-4.0 2192707) <stderr> ERROR:   File "src/gevent/greenlet.py", line 854, in gevent._gevent_cgreenlet.Greenlet.run2021-12-09 17:37:09,505 (master_driveragent-4.0 2192707) <stderr> ERROR:   File "/home/volttron/.volttron/agents/ed3ff2f3-037a-4eef-b567-3dca2c38044e/master_driveragent-4.0/master_driver/driver.py", line 163, in starting
2021-12-09 17:37:09,505 (master_driveragent-4.0 2192707) <stderr> ERROR:     self.setup_device()
2021-12-09 17:37:09,505 (master_driveragent-4.0 2192707) <stderr> ERROR:   File "/home/volttron/.volttron/agents/ed3ff2f3-037a-4eef-b567-3dca2c38044e/master_driveragent-4.0/master_driver/driver.py", line 186, in setup_device
2021-12-09 17:37:09,505 (master_driveragent-4.0 2192707) <stderr> ERROR:     self.interface = self.get_interface(driver_type, driver_config, registry_config)
2021-12-09 17:37:09,505 (master_driveragent-4.0 2192707) <stderr> ERROR:   File "/home/volttron/.volttron/agents/ed3ff2f3-037a-4eef-b567-3dca2c38044e/master_driveragent-4.0/master_driver/driver.py", line 153, in get_interface
2021-12-09 17:37:09,505 (master_driveragent-4.0 2192707) <stderr> ERROR:     module = __import__(module_name,globals(),locals(),[], 0)
2021-12-09 17:37:09,505 (master_driveragent-4.0 2192707) <stderr> ERROR: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'master_driver.interfaces.bert_plugs'
2021-12-09 17:37:09,505 (master_driveragent-4.0 2192707) <stderr> ERROR: 2021-12-09T17:37:09Z <Greenlet at 0x7f286fab0590: <bound method DriverAgent.starting of <master_driver.driver.DriverAgent object at 0x7f286fabbeb0>>(<volttron.platform.vip.agent.core.BasicCore object)> failed with ModuleNotFoundError
```

What I did was copy the `ted_meter` driver modified it accordingly in the `init.py` and placed with the other drivers here: (my new driver is called bert_plugs)

`volttron/services/core/MasterDriverAgent/master_driver/interfaces/bert_plugs/init.py`

The traceback above is from using:
`python scripts/install-agent.py -s services/core/MasterDriverAgent -c master-driver.config -f  -i platform.driver --start --enable`

Any tips greatly appreciated. I got this to work on a test VOLTTRON environment which is 8.x but for some reason hung up the 7.x version that is a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Change `init.py` to `__init__.py` and like presto it should work